# How can we redirect all pagination URL to main page

Tags: htaccess, redirects, wordpress

We want to redirect `https://www.example.com/blog/category/mobile-application/page/2/` to `https://www.example.com/blog/category/mobile-application/` or *all* blog category pagination to the main category page. How can we do it by `.htaccess` code?

We have tried this solution [Redirect all paginated pages to their main category page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/65643/redirect-all-paginated-pages-to-their-main-category-page)  but it's not working for us.

We need 301 redirects for SEO.

Comment: Please dont post links.  IT is better to post what you have tried, here.  Then someone can fix it for you.

Comment: In which directory is the `.htaccess` file located?

Comment: Given the spam we see from the site you originally asked about, explain why you now expect us to help you?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/category/mobile-application/page/2/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/blog/category/mobile-application/ [R=301,L]
```

PHP

```
 <?php
if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/blog/category/mobile-application/page/2/') {
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: https://www.example.com/blog/category/mobile-application/');
    exit;
}
?>
//Wordpress 
function ficode_redirect_category_pagination() {
  if ( is_category() && get_query_var('paged') > 1 ) {
    wp_redirect( get_category_link( get_query_var('cat') ) );
    exit;
  }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'ficode_redirect_category_pagination' );
```

Here are all the redirect [methods](https://coderpile.com/javascript/redirect-your-website-easily-with-these-code-snippets/)